# { MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am making a library nodejs application on Elementary OS. My server.js:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').config();
}
```

........

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
     useCreateIndex: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true, // commented out currently
    })
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', error => console.error(error))
db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to Mongoose'))


app.use('/', indexRouter)
app.use('/authors', authorRouter)
app.use('/books', bookRouter)


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

Each time I run 
`npm run devStart`   (I have in package.json: "devStart": "nodemon server.js")
I get this "

```
{ MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/media/dan/Alte date/aplicatii nodejs/nodejs_mongo_cc/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server_selection.js:308:9)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
  name: 'MongoTimeoutError',
  reason: 
   { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
     name: 'MongoNetworkError',
     [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
(node:6287) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/media/dan/Alte date/aplicatii nodejs/nodejs_mongo_cc/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server_selection.js:308:9)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
(node:6287) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6287) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

"

I have mongoose installed.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Check whether mongo is running..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happen if MongoDB server is not running or mongoDB URL is not proper. Is your mongoDB installed locally or it's on cloud? Also please check your connection of mongo using ROBO 3T or compass.
-Thanks

Comment: How would someone check if it is running?

Comment: there are few ways but i would recommend to use ROBO 3T. Create a connection and then press on test. If MongoDB is running you should be connected but if there is firewall issue or mongoDB not running the connection will not be establish.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem. My MongoDB is installed locally and the code is also locally. You can change localhost to 127.0.0.1 in the MongoDB URL

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should first check MongoDB is running or not? Second, if its not on the localhost, add public IP in bindIp option of mongod.conf file and then restart the mongodb server.

> bindIp:[public_ip]

And make sure you enter correct mongoDB URL.